# Использование DummyLocationManager как повысить точность и оперативность отображения объекта на карте?

Tags: android, kotlin, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

На устройстве используется отдельный модуль высокоточной навигации.
Используем режим **UserLocation** - [**UserLocationObjectListener**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/user_location/UserLocationObjectListener.html) с [**DummyLocationManager**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/location/DummyLocationManager.html) -> **[LocationManager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/location/LocationManager.html)** - в который передаем [**LocationListener**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/location/LocationListener.html) и прочие параметры:

```
val locationListener = object : LocationListener {

        override fun onLocationUpdated(location: Location) {
            //todo
        }

        override fun onLocationStatusUpdated(locationStatus: LocationStatus) {
            //todo
        }
    }
val manager = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createDummyLocationManager()
MapKitFactory.getInstance().setLocationManager(manager)
manager.subscribeForLocationUpdates(
            0.01,
            500L,
            0.0,
            true,
            FilteringMode.OFF,
            locationListener
        )
```

Модуль навигации передает координаты 1 раз в секунду в формате **GPHDT** и **GPGGA** (это максимальная скорость передачи пакетов содержащих навигационные данные)
Передаем эти данные **[Location](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/location/Location.html)** в **locationManager**

```
val location = Location(
                    MapPoint(lat, lon),
                    2.5, //радиус точности
                    altitude, //высота
                    null,
                    heading, //вектор направления объекта
                    null,
                    Date().time,
                    relativeTime // время в пакете навигационных данных
                )
 manager.setLocation(location)
```

Карта настроена следующим образом:

```
mvYandexMap.map.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
mvYandexMap.map.isTiltGesturesEnabled = false
mvYandexMap.map.set2DMode(true)
mvYandexMap.map.isModelsEnabled = false
mvYandexMap.map.poiLimit = 0
mvYandexMap.map.mapType = MapType.NONE
mvYandexMap.map.mode = MapMode.DRIVING
```

Есть две проблемы:

1. Объект отрисовывается не очень оперативно, при поступлении новых координат и вызове метода **setLocation(location)**, на карте перемещение объекта отображаются с задержкой - задержка разная - особенно это проявляется если объект изменим свое положение к примеру на 10-15 см, в таком случае порой объект на карте может и вовсе не изменить свое местоположение. Как добиться максимально оперативного изменения местоположения объекта на карте и максимально точного в сантиметровом диапазоне? Может ли на это влиять параметры метода **subscribeForLocationUpdates(desiredAccuracy, minTime, minDistance)** совместно с параметрами метода **setLocation(accuracy,speed,absoluteTimestamp,relativeTimestamp)**, как конкретно они взаимосвязаны между собой, особенно параметры самих методов , к примеру **minTime с absoluteTimestamp,relativeTimestamp**, если вообще взаимосвязаны?
2. Координаты приходят с интервалом в 1 секунду, но объект перемещается по карте от предыдущей точки к новой не плавно а рывками. Есть способ сделать плавное перемещение средствами библиотеки? Как параметры влияют на это, кроме того что координаты передаются 1 раз в секунду?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если объект на карте двигается не плавно, а рывками, то как в играх частота кадров играет роль - 1 fps - слишком мало, делайте больше. Если при этом координаты не изменяются, стоит высчитывать промежуточные точки между последними двумя (или более) и перемещать маркер уже по ним с высокой частотой.

Comment: @YaCor' Привет. Само оборудование высокоточной навигации не выдает пакеты NMEA чаще чем 1 раз секунду. Вопрос больше в том может ли сама библиотека компенсировать это "из коробки". Но этот вопрос менее критичен на самом то деле, больше интересует изменение местоположение объекта на карте в сантиметровом диапазоне. Если в DummyLocationManager передать новые координаты точки, которая отлична от предыдущей на расстояние к примеру в 5 см, то на view карты местоположение объекта не изменяется.

Comment: @YaCor' В тоже время параметры методов  subscribeForLocationUpdates и setLocation - как бы намекают на тонкую настройку обновления данных, но на практике изменение этих параметров не дает результата который можно было бы заметить, в документации очень скудное объяснение - на уровне догадайся сам. Возможно они еще между собой взаимосвязаны, как именно пока не понятно... В этом собственно и вопрос...

Comment: Можно, конечно, уточнить это напрямую у Яндекса. Но тогда возникает резонный вопрос - зачем это вообще им или кому бы то ни было нужно? Такая точность отображения бесполезна для транспорта. И нынешняя карта таких подробностей тоже не отразит. За MapKit с ходу не скажу, но плавная смена координат в JS API доступна при изменении в геометрии шестого знака после запятой, что примерно соответствует 10 см. https://jsbin.com/nirucub/1/edit?html,js,output изменения седьмого знака отрабатываются уже не каждый раз - передавать их особого смысла нет.

Comment: @YaCor' Вот как прокомментировал это Яндекс: 
_Коллеги передали, что максимальный зум поддерживаемый в MapKit = 21,
Одному пикселю на экране при таком зуме будет соответствовать 7.5см поверхности. Точное значение будет зависит от широты, но порядок приблизительно такой. Потому изменение положения на меньшие значения не будут приводить к перемещению метки._
Плюс минус примерно что и на  JS API)